# Don't Focus in MDI Form Child

Tags: c#, forms, focus, mdi

excuse my english

well i have a Form MDI Conteiner and then i open a Child Form MDI like this

```
frSeries Serie = new frSeries();            
Serie.Opener = this;
Serie.MdiParent = this;
Serie.Show();
seriesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

in the code above my Child Form receives the focus  but when i select something from one combobox that i have in this new Form the background blink

but if i create the new form like this

```
frSeries Serie = new frSeries();            
Serie.Opener = this;
Serie.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; //<----- this line is the problem
Serie.Show();
seriesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

the code above the Child Form don't receives the focus so i have to click in the child form and when i select something from one combobox that i have in this new Form the background not blink

i don't kown what is the correct form of open a MDI Form

Comment: If the form that you are creating it in is your MDIParent, it will not have a MdiParent value, therefore you are setting your new Forms MdiParent to nothing. I would use the First method.

Comment: is your mdi name frSeries?

Comment: Mark, I commented, my Form Principal is MDI Conteiner and from this i create the new form name is frSeries (that is i Child). I have use the first method because is the less that make me problem but my background Blink and this is something that i don't like, is like something is bad